Can a Brahmana do job in a company in Kali yuga?
Srimad Bhagavatam (11.17.47) explains that a brahmana may perform another occupation -
sidan vipro vanig-vrttya
panyair evapadam taret
khadgena vapadakranto
na sva-vrttya kathancana
"If a brahmana cannot support himself through his regular duties and is thus suffering, he may adopt the occupation of a merchant and overcome his destitute condition by buying and selling material things. If he continues to suffer extreme poverty even as a merchant, then he may adopt the occupation of a ksatriya, taking sword in hand. But he cannot in any circumstances become like a dog, accepting an ordinary master."
Manu smriti does allow brahmanas to perform service in case of adversity.Bhagavatam is latest grantha..hence i want to know if parashara smriti or bhagavatam allows brahmanas to do a job..thanks

Ideally Brahmanas should only perform brahmanical activities. But if the results are offered to Krishna, one can be freed from the reactions of engaging in others' duties. You may look-up Yukta-Vairagya.
